# Should I be worried about my SMART values of my drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, bad-sectors, hard-drive-failure

From what I gather, this is really really bad. I should probably replace my drive. But could I get verification that I am correct before doing so?

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR--   100   100   051    -    0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            POS---   252   252   025    -    2000
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   055   055   000    -    456175
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   068   068   010    -    305
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   085   085   000    -    7697
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   099   099   000    -    1057
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1080
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    189
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   121   088   000    -    39 (Min/Max 14/53)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    31330 (0 6)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--C-   100   100   000    -    3082
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----CK   100   100   000    -    4798
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -OS-CK   252   252   000    -    0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   -O-R--   252   252   000    -    0
```

[image: Image of screen due to formatting issues with my post]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if any of the bad sector counters (including pending, reallocated) in the SMART data of a hard disk drive are nonzero, it means the drive is dying, the error rate will only snowball (grow at an ever-accelerating rate) from here, and the drive should be replaced ASAP.